# How to install fusecompress at RHEL7?

Tags: rhel7

There is an RPM for fuse compress:

https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=fusecompress(x86-64)

So, if I do 
If I do

```
rpm -ivh fusecompress-0.6-1.0.git.20100107.5mdv2010.1.x86_64.rpm
```

I am getting

```
warning: fusecompress-0.6-1.0.git.20100107.5mdv2010.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 78d019f5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
fuse is needed by fusecompress-0.6-1.0.git.20100107.5mdv2010.1.x86_64
libboost_filesystem.so.1.42.0()(64bit) is needed by fusecompress-0.6-1.0.git.20100107.5mdv2010.1.x86_64
libboost_iostreams.so.1.42.0()(64bit) is needed by fusecompress-0.6-1.0.git.20100107.5mdv2010.1.x86_64
libboost_program_options.so.1.42.0()(64bit) is needed by fusecompress-0.6-1.0.git.20100107.5mdv2010.1.x86_64
libboost_serialization.so.1.42.0()(64bit) is needed by fusecompress-0.6-1.0.git.20100107.5mdv2010.1.x86_64
libboost_system.so.1.42.0()(64bit) is needed by fusecompress-0.6-1.0.git.20100107.5mdv2010.1.x86_64
libfuse.so.2()(64bit) is needed by fusecompress-0.6-1.0.git.20100107.5mdv2010.1.x86_64
liblzma.so.2()(64bit) is needed by fusecompress-0.6-1.0.git.20100107.5mdv2010.1.x86_64
```

However, the installation of libboost results in very many unfilled dependencies. 
There is the stack:

```
[root@tmp]# rpm -ivh libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586.rpm 
warning: libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 
Signature, key ID 70771ff3: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
libbz2.so.1 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libc.so.6 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libdl.so.2 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libexpat.so.1 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libgcc_s.so.1 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_4.0.0) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libgcc_s.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libicudata.so.42 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libicui18n.so.42 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libicuuc.so.42 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libm.so.6 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libpthread.so.0 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
librt.so.1 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libstdc++.so.6 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.5) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libutil.so.1 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
libz.so.1 is needed by libboost5-1.39.0-2mdv2010.0.i586
```

Is there any known sequence for installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what my colleague found:

```
cd '/etc/yum.repos.d/'
curl 'https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/scx/fusecompress/repo/epel-7/scx-fusecompress-epel-7.repo' > 'scx-fusecompress-epel-7.repo'
yum install -y 'fusecompress'
```